# Installing Flat Remix theme on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, 18.04, dpkg, themes

Recently, I upgraded from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Although I like the default theme but I am also interested in trying out other themes available on the web. One of them being Flat-Remix-Gnome. I followed instructions for installing the theme as given in https://github.com/daniruiz/flat-remix-gnome. But I am getting the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libkf5kdegames-data libkf5kdegames7 linux-headers-4.15.0-30
  linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  flat-remix-gnome
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/111 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,217 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 492246 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../flat-remix-gnome_3.28.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking flat-remix-gnome (3.28.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/flat-remix-gnome_3.28.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/Flat-Remix/gnome-shell/assets/calendar-arrow-left.svg', which is also in package flat-remix-gs-theme 3.12-1~xenial~NoobsLab.com
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/flat-remix-gnome_3.28.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I need help with this thing. How should I properly install flat-remix on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: If you read the error message your new theme has a file that co flicks with an alternate theme. You can force your new theme to overwrite the file, remove the old theme, file a big report .... up to you

Comment: Before anything else, I suggest you clean up your system so that you no longer see `and 4 not upgraded`. Run `sudo apt-get update`, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get autoremove.`  If you face any difficulties ask a separate question providing all the terminal output.

Comment: @DK Bose those suggustions will not address the error message

Comment: @Panther very true, but I just thought I'd point it out. The conflicting theme seems to be of 16.04 vintage: flat-remix-gs-theme 3.12-1~xenial~NoobsLab.com. I wonder what other stuff is there waiting to trip up the poster.

Comment: To avoid all hassles, proceed with manual installation as indicated on the git page of the theme. Very easy procedure. Just copy the appropriate folders from the downloaded zip files under a .themes directory in your home folder.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but I solved the issue by installing the theme directly from gnome-look.org. Then I moved the theme to .theme folder in my home directory. After that simple gnome tweak was enough to change the theme.